# Interpret Wolfram Alpha Closed Form Equation

Tags: pattern-recognition, wolfram-alpha

The closed form number pattern equation for 1, 1, 2, 6 on Wolfram Alpha is:

$a_n = (1)_{n-1}$

What does this mean?

i.e. $a_n = n$ is for 1, 2, 3, 4

Note: "n" starts at 1 (1st term)

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: What does the notation $a_n = (1)_{n-1}$ mean?

Comment: what have you typed?

Comment: Typed 1,1,2,6 @ http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=d9976f1c2c0c972d1cee0c3647cbd194

Comment: $(x)_k$ stands for $x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+k-1)$. This means $(1)_{n-1} = 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n = n!$.

Comment: @achillehui  You're right, it's a rising factorial notation a.k.a. Pochhammer function. However, the notation being used by wolfram alpha seems a bit off from the convention seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Is that a mistake?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus The difference is not limited to rising/falling factorials.  many notations on WA is different from the one documented on wiki. My personal experience is rising factorial is more common as they appear in the definition of hypergeometric function: ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{n!(c)_n} z^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the output from wolfram alpha that is the pochhammer symbol

Comment: The Online Encylopedia of Integer Sequnces has 139 pages for this entry. The first is the ordinary sequence of factorials, which is in fact the Pockhammer $(1)_n$ with the right starting point. http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+6&language=english&go=Search